# Android path pattern in deep linking

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to build a deep link into my application. The path pattern is I need to support looks something like

URLs : www.host.com/somestring-<2letters>/
example : Good URL : www.host.com/Portland-OR/
Bad URLs : www.host.com/Portland-, www.host.com/-OR, www.host.com/-, www.host.com/Por-O

So I have a set of alpha numeric set of characters that is atleast 1 character or longer. Then I have a "-" and then 2 characters exactly. I have tried

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="host.com" android:pathPrefix="/.*-.*/" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I have read the following doc and the source code around it as well.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's probably beyond what the pattern matching language for `<data>` can support.

Comment: Is it possible to say "alphanumeric-2characters" ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, sorry. It's a pretty limited pattern matcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in a static way in the `AndroidManifest.xml` but you can write your own programmatic pattern matcher in code in your `<activity>` or whatever component contains the `<intent-filter>` by extracting the `Uri` instance via `intent.getData()` and using regex or just cheaply splitting by `-` character and checking the second part.

Comment: The problem is that I dont want all the host.com urls to be handled by the app. With the solution that you mention, I would have to handle all the urls in the Android Manifest and then internally I would need to parse the url and then decide what to do with it

Comment: @LateNightDev you can try to use a subdomain instead of pattern matching on the path. like `deeplink.host.com` for all your deep links or use a custom scheme like `host://deep-link`